# how to trigger puppet agent from puppet master console v2015.2.3?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, mcollective

I am using Puppet Enterprise v2015.2.3.

I can able to trigger agent runs from the command line using MCollective, but now I want to trigger agent runs from the console.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot trigger Puppet Agent runs from the console in Puppet Enterprise 2015.2. You can only do it from MCollective.

However, [this functionality was restored in 2015.3](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/release_notes.html#run-puppet-from-the-pe-console).

[Documentation here.](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/console_classes_groups_running_puppet.html#running-puppet-on-an-individual-node)

Some quick screenshots here:
[image]

[image]